# Data Importation in R but change the delimiter from comma to semicolon

Tags: r, csv, readr

I want to change the delimiter in my data importation from comma (`,`) to semicolon (`;`) when I do that by just opening the file, it works perfectly fine, but when I want to load the data via a code line, an error occurs [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfIzC.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without the `delim=";"` also avoid `+` before the `delim=";"`

Example:

```
library(readr)

    example <- read_delim("example.csv", ";", 
        escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
```